# Save Outlook .ics file to sql database

Tags: c#, sql, outlook

I am trying to figure out how to allow my users to be able to save their outlook files to a sql database using c#/.net. I am using a normal file upload control and what I thought was I could just save it is a string but and put in a link button but that didn't work for me.

This was my idea for the code:

```
      string ImageName1 = string.Empty;

        byte[] Image1 = null;
        if (Images1.PostedFile != null && Images1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
        {
            ImageName1 = Path.GetFileName(Images1.FileName);
            Image1 = new byte[Images1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
            HttpPostedFile UploadedImage = Images1.PostedFile;
            Images1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(Image1, 0, Images1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
            UploadedImage.InputStream.Read(Image1, 0, (int)Images1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
        }
```

Any information on how to do that would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can store files as BLOBs in the database.
I don't quite follow your code, normally you call a stored procedure and pass parameters or specify the command as text in c# for communicating with the SQL server.

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives an example of how to insert blob into database.